# using function to encrypt/decrypt a string

Tags: python, encryption, ascii

I'm tryna figure out how to encrypt/decrypt a string using a single function that takes a string and an offset as parameters. depending on the offset, the function encrypts or decrypts and builds new encrypt/decrypt string

Thanks a lot!

yeah so this is what the task is asking. I'm doing it atm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBL7A.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I encrypt and decrypt a string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27335726/how-do-i-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string-in-python)

Comment: This might also help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558372/how-to-enter-the-offset-for-a-caesar-cipher-in-python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39558753/15833313 You can make changes to this to create a function. Simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what you want is a caesar cipher which is relatively simple to do in python.

```
def encrypt(text, key):
    """Encrypts text using a ceaser cypher"""
    encrypted = ""
    for char in text:
        if char.isalpha():
            encrypted += chr((ord(char) + key - 97) % 26 + 97)
        else:
            encrypted += char
    return encrypted
```

The only really weird part about this code is the unicode character madness. If you don't know unicode/ascii is a way to map numbers in a computers memory to characters which computer memory is fundamentally just 1's and 0's. here's a chart for all the relevant character

[image: https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/demarneffe.1/LING5050/material/ASCII-Table.png]